# AnyObject To CGPoint

Tags: objective-c, swift

I cant seem to figure this out, I have a Objective-C function that returns an NSArray, I know for sure that data inside the NSArray contains CGPoint objects How in the world do I cast this to an Array

Here is the function

```
+(NSArray *)translatePoints:(NSArray *)points fromView:(UIView *)fromView toView:(UIView *)toView
{
    NSMutableArray *translatedPoints = [NSMutableArray new];

    // The points are provided in a dictionary with keys X and Y
    for (NSDictionary *point in points) {
        // Let's turn them into CGPoints
        CGPoint pointValue = CGPointMake([point[@"X"] floatValue], [point[@"Y"] floatValue]);
        // Now translate from one view to the other
        CGPoint translatedPoint = [fromView convertPoint:pointValue toView:toView];
        // Box them up and add to the array
        [translatedPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:translatedPoint]];
    }

    return [translatedPoints copy];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the case? An NSArray can not directly contain CGPoints.

Comment: I see , Upon further inspection I see that it contains NSValue, so I guess then question how do you convert those to CGPoint

Comment: You would want to pull the NSValue object out of the array, downcast to NSValue and the use NSValue's CGPointValue() (IIRC)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `translatesPoints` method returns an `NSArray` that contains `NSValue`s that wrap `CGPoint`s.  Let's create such an array:

```
let arr:NSArray = [NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(1,2)), NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(3,4))]
```

You can get the values from this array and call `CGPointValue()` on them:

```
for val in arr as [NSValue] {
    let point = val.CGPointValue()
    println("CGPoint = (\(point.x), \(point.y))")
}
```

If you want, you can convert the entire `NSArray` to a Swift array of `CGPoint`s like this:

```
let points = (arr as [NSValue]).map({$0.CGPointValue()})
```

Now `points` has the type `[CGPoint]`.

Comment: Thanks, I had already figured this out, based on the comment from above. I used the for loop approach, One thing I dont get though on your convert the entire array code  what is the $0 mean.

Comment: `$0` represents the current element.  Map loops over the elements and converts each one.